# How to plot a box between two defined times & extend the box to the second defined time?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot a box from 0600 to 1200 & have the box plot to the defined end time once the 0600 candle begins trading instead of what my script currently returns, which is the box printing alongside the candles within the defined range.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqJGm.png) is an example of what my script currently does. The vertical lines are only there to delineate the beginning & endpoints of the box & are not intended to be a part of the script itself.

Additionally, I want to plot a box highlighting higher timeframe ranges. For example, plotting a box from the first full week to the end of that week in the same format I've used to highlight the sessions.

Here is the script;

```
//@version=5
indicator("AM Session Box", overlay = false)

showSessionCycles = input.bool(true, "Show Sessions")

amBgColor = color(color.new(color.green, 80))

cycleTZ = ("GMT-4")
amQ1Time = ("0600-1200")

AmQ1Logic(amQ1Time, cycleTZ = syminfo.timezone) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, amQ1Time, cycleTZ))

var AmQ1OpenPrice   = 0.0
var AmQ1High        = 2.0
var AmQ1Low         = 1.0
var box AmQ1Box     = na

isAmQ1      = AmQ1Logic(amQ1Time, cycleTZ) and timeframe.multiplier < 60
AmQ1Start   = isAmQ1 and not isAmQ1[1]

if AmQ1Start
    AmQ1OpenPrice := open

if AmQ1Start and showSessionCycles == true
    AmQ1Box := box.new(bar_index, na, na, na,
             border_color = color.black,
             border_width = 1,
             border_style = line.style_solid,
             bgcolor = amBgColor)

if isAmQ1
    box.set_top(AmQ1Box, AmQ1High)
    box.set_bottom(AmQ1Box, AmQ1Low)
    box.set_right(AmQ1Box, bar_index + 1)
```